# Inheriting List<T> to implement collections a bad idea?

Tags: c#, list, collections

I once read an article by Imaar Spaanjars on how to build 3 tier applications. (http://imar.spaanjaars.com/416/building-layered-web-applications-with-microsoft-aspnet-20-part-1) which has formed the basis of my coding for a while now.

Thus I implement collections as he has done, by inheriting a `List<T>`. So if I have a class named Employee,to implement a collection I will also have a class Employees as below.

```
class Employee
{
   int EmpID {get;set;}
   string EmpName {get;set;}  

}

class Employees : List<Employee>
{
   public Employees(){}
}
```

I never really questioned this as it did the work for me. But now that I started trying out a few things I am not sure if this is the correct approach.

e.g. if I want to get a subset from Employees, such as

```
 Employees newEmployees = (Employees) AllEmployees.FindAll(emp => emp.JoiningDate > DateTime.Now);
```

This throws a System.InvalidCastException . However, if I use the following then there is no Issue.

```
List<Employee> newEmployees = AllEmployees.FindAll(emp => emp.JoiningDate > DateTime.Now);
```

So how do I implement Employees so that I dont have to explicitly use `List<Employee>` in my DAL or BLL? Or maybe how do I get rid of the InvalidCastexception?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I wouldn't inherit from `List<T>` - it introduces issues like these, and doesn't really help (since there are no `virtual` methods to override). I would either use `List<T>` (or the more abstract `IList<T>`), or to introduce polymorphism `Collection<T>` *has* virtual methods.

As a note; re things like `FindAll`, you may also find the LINQ options (like `.Where()`) useful counterparts; most notably, they will work for *any* `IList<T>` (or `IEnumerable<T>`), not just `List<T>` and subclasses.

Comment: Right, however a small doubt. I have multiple projects like DAL and BLL, Entities and PL. Entities is where I define the classes like Employees and then use them in other projects. The idea is Each project can be worked upon independent of each other. Is there a possibility that a developer may use IList<Employee> in BLL and another developer may use Collection<Employee> in DAL, which may cause issues. The point define an implementation in Entities and let others use it wherever they want it.

Comment: @sassyboy - since `Collection<T>` implements `IList<T>`, that isn't usually an issue. Ultimately you aren't *really* defining a proper implementation by subclassing `List<T>`, since that does nothing to allow T-specific logic.

Answer (score 11):

What benefit are you getting by sub-classing `List<Employee>`? If it adds nothing then it's unnecessary code-bloat. If you're not showing methods or are enforcing contracts through a constructor that you haven't shown here then there that might be a valid reason for sub-classing.

In terms of resolving your casting problem you can't downcast from a `List<Employee>` to an `Employees` as `List<Employee>` doesn't inherit from `Employees`. If you need to return an Employees with your criteria then you're best to encapsulate the call and insert the returned list items into your own Employees object. This seems like a waste of time to me unless, like I said above, you've got a good reason to sub-class `List<Employee>`.

Personally, I'd try and use `IList<T>` where ever possible and don't create subclasses unless they have a reason to exist.

Answer (score 4):

I would personally store the list as a member of a container object, and if necesery provide get accessor to the list itself.

```
class MyCollection<T> 
{
    List<T> _table;
    public List<T> Table
    {
        get
        {
            return _table;
        }
    }
    // ... other access/utility functions common for all tables 
    //     (CRUD for example)
}

class Employees : MyCollection<Employee>
{
    // ... yet more methods 
}
```

I must admit that I did that to provide myself with methods like:

```
T FindById(int id);
void Add(T entity);
void Remove(T entity);
```

on base class and:

```
T[] GetEmployeesBy(your_filter_here);
```

I (still) use .net 2.0 so I have no linq - maybe that's the reason for it here.

Answer (score 4):

A simple rule of thumb is to start with COMPOSITION (e.g. wrap Employees around a generic collection ) and NOT INHERITANCE.  Starting off with inheritance based design is painting yourself into a corner. Composition is more flexible and modifiable.