# New C# 6 object initializer syntax?

Tags: c#, roslyn, c#-6.0

I just noticed that the following is possible in C# written in Visual Studio 2015, but I've never seen it before:

```cs
public class X
{
    public int A { get; set; }

    public Y B { get; set; }
}

public class Y
{
    public int C {get; set; }
}

public void Foo()
{
    var x = new X { A = 1, B = { C = 3 } };
}
```

My expectation was for Foo to have to be implemented like this:

```cs
public void Foo()
{
    var x = new X { A = 1, B = new Y { C = 3 } };
}
```

Note that there is no need to call `new Y`.

Is this new in C# 6? I haven't seen any mention of this in the [release notes](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6), so maybe it's always been there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# object initialization bug?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342188/c-sharp-object-initialization-bug)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will get a NullReferenceException if you run this code.

It will not create an instance of `Y`, it will call the getter of `X.B` property and try to assign value to property C.

It always worked like that. According to C# 5.0 language specification:

> A member initializer that specifies an object initializer after the equals sign is a nested object initializer, i.e. an initialization of an embedded object. Instead of assigning a new value to the field or property, the assignments in the nested object initializer are treated as assignments to members of the field or property.

Comment: You are right, thanks. So we can change the declaration of `X.B` to look like `public Y B { get; } = new Y();` and this code will work as expected. Weird that I've never noticed this syntax before!

Comment: This feature was introduced in C# 3.0

Answer (score 6):

This feature was introduced in C# 3.0 as object initializers.

See example on p. 169 of [C# Language 3.0 specification](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/8/8/388e7205-bc10-4226-b2a8-75351c669b09/CSharp%20Language%20Specification.doc):

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle {
    P1 = { X = 0, Y = 1 },
    P2 = { X = 2, Y = 3 }
};
```

which has the same effect as

```
Rectangle __r = new Rectangle();
__r.P1.X = 0;
__r.P1.Y = 1;
__r.P2.X = 2;
__r.P2.Y = 3;
Rectangle r = __r;
```