# c# confusion about iList

Tags: c#, list

I'm trying to create a new instance of the following model

```
class Input_Model
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string text {get; set;}
    public string image { get; set; }
    public IList<string> items { get; set; }
    public IList<string> tags { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public IList<string> album { get; set; }
}
```

But when I try to add an item to the items iList I get a null ref exception

Here is the code for creating the new object

```
        if(!validate_input) { MessageBox.Show("Fields missing"); return; }
        Input_Model new_entry = new Input_Model();
        new_entry.Title = title.Text;
        new_entry.Description = description.Text;
        new_entry.text = text.Text;
        new_entry.image = picture.Text;
        new_entry.items.Add("xxx");  //<--- error occurs here
```

I'm pretty sure this happens because it's an iList? but I know that I can't do

```
items = new iList<string>
```

So what's the workaround?

Comment: There is no "workaround" you need to create a `List<string>()`. Your definition is just that - only a definition, not an instance of a list. The answer in the linked duplicate describes _exactly_ your situation.

Comment: hope this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342188/initializing-list-property-without-new-list-causes-nullreferenceexception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Input_Model.items` is null when you create an instance of `Input_Model`. Create the list in the constructor:

```
class Input_Model {
    public Input_Model()
    {
        this.items = new List<string>();
    }

    // Rest of your class
}
```